# Branch.io link not showing image/thumb in Whatsapp

Tags: branch.io

I am creating a deep link using Branch.io in Android as explained in Branch docs, setting an image that I'd like to be the thumb for the link:

```
BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject = new BranchUniversalObject()
            .setCanonicalIdentifier(IDENTIFIER)
            .setTitle("Link de Teste")
            .setContentDescription("This is just a test link.")
            .setContentImageUrl("https://image-link")
            .setContentIndexingMode(BranchUniversalObject.CONTENT_INDEX_MODE.PUBLIC)
            .addContentMetadata("key", value);

    LinkProperties linkProperties = new LinkProperties()
            .setFeature("sharing")
            .addControlParameter("$desktop_url", "http://example.com/home")
            .addControlParameter("$ios_url", "http://example.com/ios");
```

When I share the link with Facebook, the image appears correctly:

[Facebook sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXsNo.jpg)

But when I share the link with Whatsapp, no image is displayed.

[Whatsapp sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXEli.jpg)

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Alex from Branch.io here: this should be working in WhatsApp, and I can confirm it does as expected with a test app on my end. I suspect WhatsApp doesn't like something about the image you're providing — could be the dimensions are wrong or unspecified. You could try our `$og_image_height` and `$og_image_width` [params](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/configuring-links/guide/#open-graph-tags) and take a look Facebook's [open graph debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) for any other errors.

Comment: We have an identical problem. Sharing from iOS to Android will show no image. Solution from Alex did not bring any success. Did you find out more about this bug?

Comment: @beseder could you share more details on exactly what isn't working? Is it sharing via WhatsApp from an iOS to an Android device? What about the other direction? Example links?

Comment: In my case, it really seems that it is as Alex said: WhatsApp in Android doesn't like something in my image (my image is an url from Firebase Storage), but I haven't discovered what is the problem yet. When I share the same link at WhatsApp from iOS, it works.

Comment: Possibly related @AlexBauer, but I'm not seeing the sample image defined in the  `link create` POST in your example Postman collection when pasting the returned deep link in a Facebook post. I have tried adding $og_image_height and width to the sample Postman but still no luck. Open graph showed an image in og:image - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.app.link%2FBdJn9t1cpM

Comment: Hmmmmm. We'll probably need to investigate further — mind emailing integrations@branch.io with the details?

Comment: Long shot but i try.. Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, I just added $og_type, $og_image_width, $og_image_height and now it's working fine, I hope this can help you [image implementation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Iqhe.png)